# App Store Updates does not renders correctly in High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update

It has been around a week that my Updates tab in the App Store looks like this:

[image]

All the other tabs are looking normal.

The only thing I tried was a restart, the iMac does not have any other weird behaviour.

Here are my details, serial hidden for privacy:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Same here, in High Sierra and El Capitan. It seems that CSS is missing or faulty. See also https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252643586

Comment: I have started having the same appearance problem with the updates section of App Store recently as well. My computer is running fine otherwise and no problem in updating the compatible apps. I have a mid-2011 27" iMac running on High Sierra (10.13.6).

Comment: I recommend submitting feedback via https://www.apple.com/feedback/ I’m getting the same issue on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App store update page doesn't seem to be loading properly on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420094/app-store-update-page-doesnt-seem-to-be-loading-properly-on-mac-os-el-capitan-1)

Comment: It was fixed recently!

Answer (score -4):

I was getting the incompatible upgrade message for GarageBand until I upgraded to MacOS Big Sur.  After I upgraded to the new  OS that error went away for me.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not Garage Band at all. I know it is just for Big Sur and my iMac is not supported for Big Sur. The problem is how the whole store tab looks.

Comment: I wonder if a less drastic install - maybe reinstalling the same OS - would help people that this issue doesn’t resolve over time with a restart.