# App store update page doesn't seem to be loading properly on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos

Basically the "updates page" loads in a non rich html format, and if theres an update it's missing the tabs on the update page as well.  I can't figure out if this is just because apple may have stopped supporting El Capitan or if I have something else going on.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've trashed the caches in library and the user profile. But this page is the only one that still loads like this (see pic below) on my app store.

[image: updatespage in app store]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418677/app-store-updates-does-not-renders-correctly-in-high-sierra

Comment: It was fixed recently!

Comment: @lhf - I'm seeing no *useful* change on El Cap. The CSS issue has been solved - it now says "No updates found" in a nice font;) … but it still doesn't connect to Purchases.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the info, I no longer have an El Capitan system to check.

Answer (score 6):

It's been that way for quite a while - I'd assume it's simply no longer supported for El Cap, but I have no citation for that.

You have to bear in mind that there will no longer be any updates for any apps on El Capitan [nor indeed for the OS itself] - many apps are now minimum spec Mojave, some a little older some newer, but no-one is going to be testing against El Capitan any more. It was superseded 5 years ago & generally support is to 3 years.

As noted, this applies up to High Sierra - the only difference on High Sierra is it lists all the updates you *can't have*, also in plain text ;)

[image]

Comment: I called apple and spoke to 3 advisors, including head tech and they said it's not supposed to show up like this.  Yet they were unable to solve the issue.  When I tried updating to High Sierra-same issue.  I tried Mojave,  then my Notes app started Facetime.  No matter how I installed it, so I had to revert back to El Capitan.  I tried High Sierra, fresh install and Mojave.  I can't seem to get rid of that bug either.  However the issue doesn't seem to be in guest user; so somehow my notes is pulling some preference.  I just don't know how to migrate my data back

Comment: You cannot 'migrate downhill' you must have a complete clone to revert to.

Comment: I wiped the drive clean and then did a time machine restore to go back.

Comment: no other issues for el capitan other than the update store view.  All works:)  When moving forward to Mojave, I get the Notes launching FaceTime issue. (

Comment: You've got to be really careful with Time Machine. if it backs up even once on the newer OS you can lose the ability to go back. The wise move is to disconnect it if you're testing newer OSes. The smart money is also on distinct clones at each step - but that depends on how many spare hard drives you have. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/271104/85275 for a sad & sorry tale ;)

Comment: Good to know.  That's a great idea moving forward.  Thanks. My Time Machine is not set to automatic :)   Which Cloner tool do you use. Carboncloner?

Comment: Yes Carbon Copy Cloner - I've never tried any others, always just that, so idk how they actually compare.

Comment: I looked at that link.   yes if you move back and wait too long on TimeMachine.  However if you have an email issue, you can change the V5 to V3 and it will restore all email.

Comment: I wish I'd known that 4 years ago. Do want to drop an answer in there?

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420098/notes-in-mojave-launches-facetime

Comment: Not a clue, sorry :\

Answer (score 5):

This is a known problem. On all osx versions prior to Mojave Appstore is displayed in "text" mode. CSS issue not resolved to date.
This does not, it seems, interfere with proper operation.