# What If App Store Purchases Can't Be Viewed?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-appstore, error

The App Store connects, and all the tabs work — except the Purchases tab. That tab "Cannot Connect to the App Store".

So, I cannot install any of the apps I brought from the App Store.

The strangest thing is that I cannot find a single example anyone else, on the *internet*, who has shares this.

My config…

- Fresh install; no apps from the App Store installed.
- Macbook Pro 17" (Yes, one of *those* people).
- High Sierra 10.13.16 with all Apple updates.
- App Store is fine on my other Macs with same Apple ID.
- Date and time are correct. (But they were not when I first installed — I fixed in 45 secs.)
- No stuck downloads.
- iTunes Store seems to work fine.

What I've tried…

- Signing in/out of App Store.
- Deleted all in ~/Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Cookies.
- No VPN.
- Creating a second account with same Apple ID
- Safe Mode
- Deleted /var/db/crls/crlcache2.db
- Reset DigiCert High Assurance EV root CA
- Deleted ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
- Set DNS to 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8
- Set csrutil to active
- Unleashed ferrets

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Bill

Comment: This is a known issue with no solution [other than updating to Mojave] for all OSes prior to that. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420094/app-store-update-page-doesnt-seem-to-be-loading-properly-on-mac-os-el-capitan-1/420096#420096