# App Store Broken

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore

2010 MacPro running 10.13.6 High Sierra.

I see this on the app store, not the normal page -

[image]

When I click to restart/install, I get a message "Available updates have changed" / "Click 'show details' to see the available updates. But that does nothing. A restart doesn't install the updates available.

I'm looking for a way to reinstall the App Store App.
FWIW, I updated from Yosemite to High Sierra recently and hadn't seen this issue before the update. Mostly all else running fine.

The odd page rendering isn't the real issue, it's the fact that the update(s) offered to me don't install, just the cycle of error messages. **Other linked answer has no solution to that problem either.**

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418677/app-store-updates-does-not-renders-correctly-in-high-sierra

Comment: RE: "The odd page rendering isn't the real issue, it's the fact that the update(s) offered to me don't install" --  In **Terminal**: `man softwareupdate`  Then use it to install updates.

Comment: sorry, yes, i'll try that. thanks.

Comment: Is there one update you need to run? Editing that in the question might help others realize this is more about the functional update as opposed to the visual glitch. I could possibly help script that one update in my answer as well if all updates don’t run.

Comment: Type in Terminal `softwareupdate -i -a`

Comment: Please don't add answers or replies to comments directly to the question. If applicable post an answer instead.

Comment: Sorry if that broke a norm. I can’t load an image to reply to comment, and the image showed I entered the suggested code correctly along with the exact result from terminal. Either way, I will not do that again.

Comment: It was fixed recently!

Comment: Wow, saw your comment, and signed into the store. It's fixed. Shocked.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS needed to render the old App Store is not being served. That [explains only the visual change](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/420094/5472), not the lack of function.

You may need to update the OS or use a [command line tool like mas](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) if you can’t operate the controls without the web app rendering properly.

- [App store update page doesn't seem to be loading properly on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420094/)
- [App Store Updates does not renders correctly in High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/418677/5472)

For security updates, you should be able to run `softwareupdate -aiR` from terminal and avoid the app needing to function at all. Should that fail a backup and restore or deeper triage is needed to isolate what’s causing the failure to operate in that app.

Comment: Much appreciated. If the update process worked, I would not care about the rendering. I can't load the Security update being offered.

Comment: If the GUI isn’t working, you should use the command line or perhaps conclude there are two issues, the CSS and issues with the Mac downloading the update @JTP-ApologisetoMonica